# How can I convert my Excel VBA Macros to EXE File?

Tags: excel, vba, exe

I have prepared lots of Excel based Tools using excel macros. In these Excel Sheets user normally browses Excel files or inputs data as guided by the tool and then runs my macros to generate a desired output. Everything is working fine.

However, instead of distributing these tools as Excel sheets, can I convert my codes to a exe file and distribute it to users who can run it there?

I searched a lot on Excel to exe related threads but didn't get a satisfying answer hence thought of starting a new thread.

Comment: It will be much slower. Using ane EXE means outofprocess activation which is much slower than inprocress. However you only need to rewrite parts of it (global objects now need to be instanced, constants need to have numeric value put in).

Comment: Welcome to SO. First answer: Nope, you can't. Second answer, Nope, you can't, but probably you could design something with VB (note VB is not VBA), because syntax is similar (but they do are different). If your code is not complex, and it works selecting Excel Files, you could design in VB a simple [Microsoft Form app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-a-visual-basic-winform-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017), and then apply your code (you will have to adapt some parts, but not all of it. Give it a try

Answer (score 7):

This answer might not be satisfying too but the fact is that Excel is no programming tool to produce stand alone applications (exe).

Therefore you need to re-write your project using a *real* programming language (and tool) like VB.NET or C#. VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) is meant to run in applications as its name says (like Excel or other Office applications) but not stand alone.

There is no way of just converting the code (by pressing a button or something) you will need to re-write the whole project/tool completely (by hand) in another programming language if you plan to use your application stand alone (exe) without Excel.

Please note that even if VBA and VB.NET use similar syntax you cannot just copy the code. These are 2 completely different languages and the code needs to be re-written. Even if the result would look *similar* it is not the same.

Comment: thank you for the reply. No my misconception on a easy way out to generate a exe using my code is cleared... i will try using visual studio and rewrite my code

Answer (score 4):

Your solution is not the answer to your need. What you actually want is an Add-In file that you can distribute to your users. This file extends Excel and gives users access to your tools, but can be password protected and hidden so users can't mess with it . At it's simplest it's just a case of saving the workbook containing your code as a file of type Add-in, but you do need to rewrite your code to make explicit which workbook you are working with, since ThisWorkbook in your code is the add-in, and ActiveWorkbook is the file that the user has open while using your addin. You will also need to develop menus to give users access to your tools, since they can't see the add-in.

Answer (score 3):

You can only do that if you do it outside excel, write a program in a Windows development tool which is able to communicate between applications. You can use many Microsoft development platforms for this, f.e. C#.

What you want to do is start a process to interfere with another process.

How to do it depends a lot on the targetted windows-version. It is not an easy subject, and I don't know if you really want to go this way. But if you do, Google on inter-process communication and Windows.

This is a nice overview article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ipc/interprocess-communications