# convert Userform (VBA) to exe

Tags: vba

I tried converting it to VB6 but most components / controls are not working in Windows 10.
My entire coding is done using Userform and the instance of excel is also used externally so there is no reference to my base workbook. Is there a possibility to create exe with code encryption? Did a lot of research but couldn't find anything conclusive.

Comment: No, you cannot just convert it from VBA to an EXE - You would have to rewrite it in VB6.

Comment: The code should be pretty similar tho, so redraw the form in VB6, name everything the same, then copy/paste the code from VBA and adjust it for the slight differences.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53002366/how-can-i-convert-my-excel-vba-macros-to-exe-file