# How to convert ".exe" from ".xlsm" excel macro file or to secure vba file

Tags: excel, vba, security, secure-coding

I want to encrypt the VBA file no one can check the code. To secure the VBA file. I know about "VBE Project Properties-> lock" and I don't make it execute from the VBS file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53002366/how-can-i-convert-my-excel-vba-macros-to-exe-file

Comment: Excel security is basically pointless. That said, there are some commercial products that may offer some more protection, e.g. https://www.exceltoexe.com/